# How does Mac OS X set the value of $PATH?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, path

I have a basic understanding on how the $PATH can be set, but is there a documentation that fully describes where Mac OS gets *all* the paths that get appended to $PATH? I'm aware of things like `/etc/profile`, `/etc/paths`, and `/etc/profile.d`, but are there other scripts that eventually affect the value of $PATH? I'm also not very familiar between the non-login, and login shells (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`), but I'm aware of the basic differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, your PATH is set by the shell. For Bash, everything is [explained in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). You can also open `man bash` and skip to the `INVOCATION` part.

> #### Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
>
> #### Invoked as an interactive non-login shell
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.
>   In OS X, additionally, there is [`path_helper`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html) which reads the contents of `/etc/paths.d` and appends those to your path.

The key here is that on OS X, the Terminal opens a login shell by default, while on Linux, shells are usually started as non-login shells. Josh Staiger has [a good explanation of login vs non-login shells](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

So, there are essentially only these two three where you can set paths:

- `/etc/profile` (which calls `path_helper`)
- `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d` (called from `path_helper`)
- your shell configuration file (`.bash_profile`)

Comment: Thanks for the concise, and informative answer. So I guess I kind of understand, which scripts/artifacts influence the $PATH then. So does this mean the `/etc/profile` is a script mainly used by bash? I don't have experiences with other shells, but I assume they follow a different structure?

Comment: The `/etc/profile` is used by most (all? Not 100% sure) shells. That's why it's a good choice to put things in that you want everywhere, like PATHs. Bash reads `.bash_` files while Zsh for example reads `.zshrc` in addition to others. It depends on the shell.

Comment: "In OS X, additionally, there is path_helper which reads the contents of /etc/paths.d and appends those to your path." No, `path_helper` is *not* called for interactive non-login shells (nor non-interactive shells). It is called for interactive login shells, by `/etc/profile` actually.

Answer (score 8):

The paths in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*` are typically added to `PATH` by [path_helper](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/path_helper.html). `path_helper` is run from `/etc/profile`, so it is run when bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, but not when bash is invoked as a non-login shell or a non-interactive shell.

`/etc/paths` contains `/usr/local/bin` at the end by default, and `/etc/paths.d/` is empty by default.

Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells by default, and the shell opened when you ssh to your computer is also a login shell. Many terminal emulators on other platforms, `tmux`, and the shell mode in Emacs open new shells as non-login shells though.

I have added this line to `/etc/launchd.conf`:

`setenv PATH ~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/libexec:/usr/texbin`

It changes the value of `PATH` of the root launchd process. The value is inherited by all other processes, including per-user launchd processes. You can apply changes to `/etc/launchd.conf` by restarting, or by running `launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf; sudo launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf` and relaunching processes.

On OS X, `~/.profile` is not read when you log in graphically. If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist, bash does not read `~/.profile` either.

`~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` stopped working in 10.8.