# How to remove Anaconda PATH?

Tags: bash, zsh, path, anaconda

I have uninstalled Anaconda from MacOS but still there is on the PATH. I have searched all `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc` but I did not find anywhere that set the Anaconda path.
It is available on both `bash` and `zsh`.

How can I find where it is set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Mac OS X set the value of $PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/653803/how-does-mac-os-x-set-the-value-of-path)

Comment: Finally find it in ```/etc/paths```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc`, but most if you do not have a `.zsh_profile`, it wll also look in your `.profile`. Try looking in your:

```
.profile
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.zsh_profile
.zshrc
```

If any of them does not exist, it is not that one. If it is not in those, try finding a anaconda uninstall script. it might be added in /etc/*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).